# How do i calculate the average salary of all employees from an internal table in abap?

Tags: abap

I created a class that has the attributes (name ,address ,age ,salary). I created employee objects in an internal table defined as follows

```
 Data itab_employees  TYPE TABLE OF REF TO lcl_employee.
```

Is it possible to create a method that calculates the average of the salaries of the employee objects that are inside internal table (itab_employees)?

This what i tried so far

```
METHOD get_avg_salary.
DATA: r_employee  TYPE REF TO lcl_employee,
      getsalary   TYPE i,
      average     TYPE i,
      sum_salary  TYPE i,
      no_employee TYPE i.

getsalary = r_employee->get_salary( ).
no_employee = lcl_employee=>get_n_o_employee( ).

LOOP AT it_employees INTO r_employee.
  AT LAST.
    SUM .
    sum_salary = getsalary.
    average    =  sum_salary / no_employee.
  ENDAT.
ENDLOOP.
re_avg_salary = average.
ENDMETHOD.
```

But i am not sure about the line
`getsalary = r_employee->get_salary( ).`

Comment: Show us at least what you tried so far and where you are having a problem.

Comment: It's almost certainly possible, yes. You'll need to loop over `itab_employees` into an object variable, which you will add to some variable called, say, `total`. Once you've looped through the objects, divide `total` by the amount of objects in your table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your comments @gkubed. I figured something out which worked out for me

```
  METHOD get_avg_salary.
DATA: r_employee  TYPE REF TO lcl_employee,
      average     TYPE i,
      sum_salary  TYPE i.

LOOP AT it_employees INTO r_employee.
    sum_salary =  sum_salary +  r_employee->get_salary( ).
ENDLOOP.
average    =  sum_salary / sy-tfill.
re_avg_salary = average.
ENDMETHOD.
```

Comment: Well, I would use `lines( it_employees )` instead of `sy-tfill`

Comment: Thanks @LPK of your comment

Comment: Alternatively, if working on an ABAP 7.4 system, one may use a [table reduction](https://help.sap.com/abapdocu_750/en/abenconstructor_expression_reduce.htm). It would look sort of like this: 
`average = REDUCE i(
 INIT a = 0 
 FOR r_employee IN it_employees 
 NEXT a = a + r_employee->get_salary( ) ) / lines( it_employees ). ` This is a _side effect free_ approach without the need for intermediate variables.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas Matecki of your comment, it helped.